# DatePicker explotes when try to choose the max date

Tags: android, datepicker, android-datepicker

I've implemented a **DatePickerFragment** inside my activity. This DatePicker have a min date and max date to choose.

The problem is on Android Version 4.1.2, when I try to open the DatePicker, on click, it explote.
On Android Verion 5 not happens (the display of the datepicker is different)

This is the part of code when the date picker explotes:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Date maxDate;
        Date minDate;
        // datepicker
        DatePickerDialog dig = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).anio, ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).mes, ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).dia);
        dig.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
        // maxima fecha
        ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).cc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +10);
        maxDate = ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).cc.getTime();
        dig.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTime());
        // minima fecha
        ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).cc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -10);
        minDate = ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).cc.getTime();
        dig.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTime());


        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return dig;
    }
```

**This is the line where the date picker explotes:**

```
dig.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTime());
```

This is the error messagge:

```
06-06 13:24:17.709 5018-5018/com.sourcey.model E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Time not between Mon Jun 06 13:24:16 ART 2016 and Thu Jun 16 13:24:16 ART 2016
                                                                          at android.widget.CalendarView.goTo(CalendarView.java:1103)
                                                                          at android.widget.CalendarView.setMinDate(CalendarView.java:761)
                                                                          at android.widget.DatePicker.setMinDate(DatePicker.java:344)
                                                                          at com.sourcey.model.ReservarTurnos$DatePickerFragment.onCreateDialog(ReservarTurnos.java:753)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.getLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:308)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:798)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:565)
                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Someone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
We have to put:

```
 minDate = ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).cc.getTime();
        dig.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTime());
```

before than:

```
        ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).cc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, +10);
        maxDate = ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).cc.getTime();
        dig.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(maxDate.getTime());
        // minima fecha
        ((ReservarTurnos)getActivity()).cc.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot have exact mindate.

```
dig.getDatePicker().setMinDate(minDate.getTime()+10);
```

This might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
```

And also set `mindate` code, before `maxdate`.